# meaning of "maintaining moral and ethical standards" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

One of the issues from the [pool of GRE analytical writing issue topics](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/issue/pool) is as follows:

> To be an effective leader, a public official must **maintain the highest ethical and moral standards**.
>
> *Write a response in which you discuss the extent to which you agree or disagree with the claim. In developing and supporting your position, be sure to address the most compelling reasons and/or examples that could be used to challenge your position.*

In above-mentioned statement, I do not understand what "maintaining the highest ethical and moral standards" mean. Does it mean that the leader should act according to the morals in his personal life, or that the leader needs to encourage other people to do so?
Or, maybe it can convey both meanings and it depends on how I interpret it.

Comment: I just want to suggest that may be you should wait a few more hours after asking a question to select an answer as your accepted one. If you wait, you will get more answers. If you accept an answer within just an hour, your question will not get as much attention as it would have had you not accepted the first answer so quickly. Please see this: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer). Others may give better answers - but I am glad you upvoted mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bold part applies to both the public official himself and his team/administration/community. You can write about one or both - the question is open ended. But as it is, I think most people sitting for the exam will most likely talk about the public official himself and how his principles affect those around him.

It is implied. If I adhere to *"the highest ethical and moral standards"* then I will be aware and critical of anyone doing anything unethical or immoral around me. If they do something that is unethical, I would take action because the unethical act has upset or offended me. Essentially, I am maintaining the standard around me - not just in my personal life. If I am ethical, I will automatically lead in an ethical way. That will encourage my team to do the same as well.

Note how the question is not *"To be an effective leader, a **person** must maintain the highest ethical and moral standards."*

The use of "public official" tells you that you need to bring into light how his ethics and morals affect those around him - which may include this team or the people of his community.

Also, a public official serves the people of the community. To be a great leader and to lead by example, he will need to maintain such standards both in his personal life and in his professional/official one.

(him = her = they)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It cleared things up for me. But, still I'm wondering can "maintaining highest moral standards" imply, in a way, some sort of dictatorship? for example, if we go back in time when homosexuality was not ethically accepted, if a leader wanted to maintain highest moral standards, he would not allow people to have homosexual relationships. Is such an argument relevant to the statement or it is completely off topic?

Comment: I would personally not write anything that is controversial in my GRE exam. We are emotional beings - you don't know who is grading your exam. What you say can be a possibility. I won't use the term "dictatorship" - that is irrelevant. I think what you are trying to say is that "What if one's standards are biased/prejudiced?" Am I correct? What you are getting into is the "character" of the leader. A mafia leader will have a set of principles - to him backstabbing and stealing from him is unethical - but selling drugs is not. But I feel that is off-topic.

Comment: In general, a public official is voted - there is less chance that his moral guideline will be detrimental to his community. If we are talking about a tyrant - then we are not talking about a leader.

Comment: A violation of morality for a "leader" would be if he denounced homosexuality to fit in with the higher class people who do the same - but in reality the "leader" is gay.